# diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 not work with all software after upgrating to 16.04 - OpenSSH_7.2p2

Tags: 16.04, lts, openssh

I have upgraded 2 computer with Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS and I have a problem with openssh.

With software like Putty 0.64 and less for example I can't establiseh a conexion with diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 or diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1. 
The first working is diffie-hellman-group14-sha1.

Before the upgrade it work well, and on an other computer with 14.04LTS it continu to works well with putty 0.64 and less with diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256.

It's strange because with Putty 0.65 and more continu to work well.

So I think my configuration is still good, and it is the same of the working Ubuntu 14.04.

Is it a bug on OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should not use out-of-date software in the first place, especially for something as security-critical as an SSH client.

Comment: Thanks, I know, I have see this problem, and I think it is not safe to keep it problem on OpenSSH, so I share it.
Could you this it can be a problem on Putty ?
If we use diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 on an older on a newer software it's not the same ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found when connecting to various ssh servers (in this case, ones run by financial institutions), that for many the diffie-hellman-group-exchange methods do no work with Ubuntu 16, while they worked fine with Ubuntu 14. It has to do with negotiating the key size after accepting the method. The OpenSSH in Ubuntu 16 won't accept less than an 2048 bit key, while the older OpenSSH accepted a shorter key in this context. The work around for the client is to exclude those. So in /etc/ssh/ssh_config I have:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

The first line, allowing DSS, I know is less secure. But the connections are needed, and I don't control those servers. The second is the full list of supported key exchange methods (ssh -Q kex) with just the two problematic diffie-hellman-group-exchange-* methods left out. It would probably be better practice to list those in the reverse order, as this can be take as order-of-preference, and the list as I have it puts the newer, stronger methods last. In any case, leaving out the ones that won't work with the servers you need to connect with, or alternately specifying a single, known-compatible on one the command line, is the way around the problem you and I have seen.